# Google Sheet Export range as CSV change header value

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-apps-script

My objective is to export specific columns of data from my sheet as a CSV file. The columns that are exported are designated by their column header name. This is required as new columns are occasionally added/removed from the sheet. In the export it is also important that these header values are changed as the program that the CSV is being imported to requires specific header values that are not always the same as what is used in my sheet. As there are over 20 different types of exports that need to be done from the sheet it does not make sense to create queries on separate tabs for download. As I have shown in the example file and script, this CSV export also requires that a From & To Date column is added to the data.

In short, I need to export columns based on their header value and change the header value that shows in the export.

So far the script works as it creates a new folder and file with a CSV containing the columns that I need based on the column headers which can then be downloaded using a url link. Where I am stuck is:

1. I need to change the column headers in the CSV export. For example, I need the header for column 2 to be "Short Description" but in the sheet that I am exporting from the header is "Delivery Product Name".
2. Preferably, I would like to delete the folder and file that are created in order to generate the link which is used to download the CSV. This is only a preference as the users could just manually delete the folder.

Example workbook: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k83XFeeItHgKvC9O9-YwY1pQQjb52E3-dnt0w4gCJnM/edit?usp=sharing

```
function WebInterface_CSVB() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_') + '_csv_' + new Date().getTime());
  fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
  var csvFile = Convert_WebInterfaceB(fileName, sheet);
  var file = folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  var downloadURL = file.getDownloadUrl().slice(0, -8);
  WebInterface_urlB(downloadURL);
}

function WebInterface_urlB(downloadURL) {
  var link = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<a href="' + downloadURL + '">Click here to download</a>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(link, 'Your CSV file is ready!');
}

function Convert_WebInterfaceB(csvFileName, sheet) {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  const sh = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  const allvalues = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow()-1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()                   // Get values (Row,Column,OptNumRows,OptNumColumns) 
  const header1 = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().indexOf("SKU");
  const header2 = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().indexOf("Delivery Product Name");
  const header3 = sh.getRange(1, 1, 1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues().flat().indexOf("Delivery Product Description");  
  var date1 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var date2 = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().setFullYear(new Date().getFullYear() + 1)), "GMT+1", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var data = allvalues.map(function(o){return [o[header1],o[header2],o[header3],date1,date2]});

  try {
    var csvFile = undefined;
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
 


  [1]: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k83XFeeItHgKvC9O9-YwY1pQQjb52E3-dnt0w4gCJnM/edit?usp=sharing
```

Comment: I'm basically trying to get from
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gV8dO6LbpZ64S-jjR-g8w-JYYhYORXDp/view?usp=drive_link
To:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qOdhqb-5W-kMOmjzCBJDU0HdB_obdp5D/view?usp=drive_link

Comment: Tedinoz I have edited my explanation. Hopefully it is clearer? Regardless thanks for taking the time to look at it.

Comment: How were you thinking of identifying the State date and End date? I've been playing with using a modal with a jquery datepicker; I can get the selections but haven't managed to get the values from the dialog yet :)

Comment: OK, my answer uses "Today" and "Today+1 day" (tomorrow.) So that's easy to change to Today+ 1 year. FWIW, I figured out how to use a `datepicker` to select the dates.

Comment: Yeah even with my lack of knowledge I figured out the change to +1 year lol. Really wish Stack Over Jobs was still a thing as scripts are not my area of expertise in which I end up spending hours trying to figure something out only to have someone such as yourself fix it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to change the header values in certain columns, and add additional columns containing start and end dates.

---

**function WebInterface_CS**: Very minor (possibly unnecessary) changes only.

- formatted a different `time` value to use for file save; probably can be ignored, but I couldn't follow the time values in the original script.

**function Convert_WebInterface**: No changes after `try` (line 77)

- shortened/simplified `indexOf` code; used the existing data array
- assigned replacement header values

  - `allvalues[0][header2] = "Short Description"` and following
- created variables for the start and end dates; `var startingDate` and following
- created variables for start and end headers; `var header4 = "Start Date"` and following
- created temporary arrays for the start and end dates, added the headers, and used a loop to add the date values; `var startArray = []` and following
- added the temporary arrays to the existing (3 column) data array; `data[i].push(startArray[i][0],endArray[i][0])` and following

The result is a 2D array (`data`) that is ready for converting to CSV and saving.

I

---

```
function WebInterface_CSV() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Database');
  var folderTime = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "yyyy-MM-dd'_'HH:mm:ss")
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Folder date = "+folderTime) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Proposed folder name: "+ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_') + '_csv_' + folderTime) // DEBUG
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Proposed file name: "+sheet.getName() + ".csv") // DEBUG
  
  var folder = DriveApp.createFolder(ss.getName().toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,'_') + '_csv_' + folderTime);
  var fileName = sheet.getName() + ".csv";
  var csvFile = Convert_WebInterface(fileName, sheet);
  var file = folder.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  var downloadURL = file.getDownloadUrl().slice(0, -8);
  WebInterface_url(downloadURL);
}

function WebInterface_url(downloadURL) {
  var link = HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<a href="' + downloadURL + '">Click here to download</a>');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(link, 'Your CSV file is ready!');
}

function Convert_WebInterface(csvFileName, sheet) {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  const sh = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  const allvalues = sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getValues()      // Get values (Row,Column,OptNumRows,OptNumColumns) 
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Database range = "+sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getLastRow(),sh.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation())
  
  // get the column Index of the headers
  const header1 = allvalues[0].indexOf("SKU")
  const header2 = allvalues[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Name")
  const header3 = allvalues[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Description")
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: Header Index values: #1 = "+header1+", #2 = "+header2+", #3 = "+header3)
  
  
  // Assign replacement values
  allvalues[0][header2] = "Short Description"
  allvalues[0][header3] = "Long Description"

  // extract only the columns that relate to the headers  
  var data = allvalues.map(function(o){return [o[header1],o[header2],o[header3]]})

  // add the Start/End dates 
  var startingDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  var startingDatePlusOne = new Date((new Date()).valueOf() + 1000*3600*24);
  var endingDate = Utilities.formatDate(startingDatePlusOne, "GMT-8", "yyyy-MM-dd")
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: start date = "+startingDate+", ending date = "+endingDate)

  // add headers for the Start and End dates 
  var header4 = "Start Date"
  var header5 = "End date"
  // create temporary arrays to hold the date values
  var startArray = []
  var endArray = []
  // push the headers onto the arrays
  startArray.push([header4])
  endArray.push([header5])
  // get the number of rows for the loop
  var lr = sh.getLastRow()
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: the last row is "+lr)
  
  // build the temporary arrays
  // start=1 to ignore header
  for (var i=1;i<lr;i++){  
    startArray.push([startingDate])
    endArray.push([endingDate])
  }
  // Logger.log(startArray) // DEBUG
  // Logger.log(endArray) // DEBUG

``// add the start and end date array to the data
  for( var i=0;i<12;i++){
    data[i].push(startArray[i][0],endArray[i][0])
  }
  // Logger.log(data) // DEBUG

  try {
    var csvFile = undefined;

    // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
//        if (row < data.length) {
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}

///// Alternate Script if Needed;
// Quotes themselves must be escaped (double them -> " becomes "")
// Commas must be escaped (put string in quotes)
//New lines must be escaped (put string in quotes)

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName, sheet) {
  try {
    var data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var rows = [];
      data.forEach(row => {
        var cols = [];
        row.forEach(col => {
          cols.push(`"${col.replace(/"/g, '""')}"`);
        });

        rows.push(cols.join(','));
      });
      
      return rows.join('\n');
    }
  } catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

---

**SAMPLE-OUTPUT**

[image: output]

---

**REVISION#2 TO CATER FOR FIELDS CONTAINING COMMAS**

Some data cells contain commas and these commas should be retained in the CSV file. The solution for this is in two parts:

- a map function to wrap the entire cell in double quotes; as explained by @Tanaike in [How can I include commas when creating CSV files with Google apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56435499/1330560)
- modifying the data loop to insert `"\r\n"` ONLY between each row

**Issues**

Some cells (such as the product description for SKU: 817192) contain commas AND double quotes. This something for the OP to resoolve.

---

```
function Convert_WebInterface(csvFileName, sheet) {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  const sh = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  var lc = sh.getLastColumn()
  var lr = sh.getLastRow()
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).getValues()

  // get the column Index of the headers
  const header1 = data[0].indexOf("SKU")
  const header2 = data[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Name")
  const header3 = data[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Description")
  const header4 = data[0].indexOf("PL Region/Country")
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Header Index values: #1 = "+header1+", #2 = "+header2+", #3 = "+header3+", #4 = "+header4)

  // Assign replacement values
  data[0][header2] = "Short Description"
  data[0][header3] = "Long Description"
  
  // extract only the columns that relate to the headers  
  var data = data.map(function(o){return [o[header1],o[header2],o[header3],o[header4]]})
  data = data.map(function(e) {return e.map(function(f) {return ~f.indexOf(",") ? '"' + f + '"' : f})})
  // Logger.log("data rows = "+data.length+", data columns = "+data[0].length)

  var csvFile = undefined

  // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
}
```

---

**SAMPLE OUTPUT**

[image: revision2]

---

**REVISION#3: convert existing double quotes to Unicode**

```
/*
// convert data to csv
// REVISION#1
// limit array columns to nominated header values
// REVISION#2 
// some cells contain commas; 
// wrap and cell containing a comma in double quotes 
// REVISION#3
// some cells contain double quotes;
// convert existing double quotes to unicode 
*/

function Convert_WebInterface(csvFileName, sheet) {
  const wb = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();  
  const sh = wb.getSheetByName("Database");
  var lc = sh.getLastColumn()
  var lr = sh.getLastRow()
  var data = sh.getRange(1,1,lr,lc).getValues()

  // get the column Index of the headers
  const header1 = data[0].indexOf("SKU")
  const header2 = data[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Name")
  const header3 = data[0].indexOf("Delivery Product Description")
  const header4 = data[0].indexOf("PL Region/Country")
  // Logger.log("DEBUG: Header Index values: #1 = "+header1+", #2 = "+header2+", #3 = "+header3+", #4 = "+header4)

  // Assign replacement values
  data[0][header2] = "Short Description"
  data[0][header3] = "Long Description"
  
  // extract only the columns that relate to the headers  
  var data = data.map(function(o){return [o[header1],o[header2],o[header3],o[header4]]})

  // convert double quotes to unicode
  //loop over the rows in the array
  for (var row in data) {
    //use Array.map to execute a replace call on each of the cells in the row.
    var data_values = data[row].map(function(original_datavalue) {
      return original_datavalue.toString().replace('"', '＂');
    })
    //replace the original row values with the replaced values
    data[row] = data_values;
  }


  // wrap any value containing a comma in double quotes
  data = data.map(function(e) {return e.map(function(f) {return ~f.indexOf(",") ? '"' + f + '"' : f})})
  
  // Logger.log("data rows = "+data.length+", data columns = "+data[0].length)

  var csvFile = undefined
  // loop through the data in the range and build a string with the csv data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var dataRow = 0; dataRow < data.length; dataRow++) {

        // join each row's columns
        // add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (dataRow < data.length-1) {
          // valid data row
          csv += data[dataRow].join(",") + "\r\n";
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: row#"+dataRow+", csv = "+data[dataRow].join(",") + "\r\n")
        }
        else {
          csv += data[dataRow];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
}
```

---

[image: revision3]

Comment: Tedinoz, thank you. Worked perfectly and with your notes I think I actually understand it lol.

Comment: Tedinoz, looks like I celebrated too soon. It appears that some of the characters in my actual data or causing errors........
New York, USA  ⇨ NaN........
Modern  | Med-Sweet  ⇨ NaN........
Bright, crisp apple flavor, just right   ⇨  NaN........
Crisp Apple, 4 x 473 ml   ⇨  NaN........
(Euro) Clear golden; aroma   ⇨  NaN........

Comment: I've created a new workbook that is using your code with some more accurate data here:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h8NErXDvAFlSIw6UXWvhpjKtHioPtp_FBjv4AHxWfyQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I have written a script that demonstrates how the issue can be resolved. You'll note that some fields contain both commas AND double quotes. This is beyond the scope of this question and is something for you to consider the range of possible solutions.

Comment: Tedinoz, understood. I will post a new thread to address the change in scope. Thanks for responding and again thanks for the solution as I'm sure the final changes will be figured out.

Comment: No worries. I think a thorough review of your data is necessary. For example, I was going to suggest that the script could change any `existing` double quotes to single quotes. But then I realised that the cell might also contain single quotes, and the resulting text might not "read" as one would wish.

Comment: I think I've got it. Replace existing conventional double quotes with `＂` (Unicode &#65282;). Use the method described in function `replaceInSheet` from [Create a google Script for finding and replacing text in the same cell on each page of a spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66645395/1330560).

Comment: @MicahNoble Have a look at revision#3. Can't speak for every cell in every column, but this works with my test data.

Comment: So close. the only error I have found is if there is more than 1 quotation mark in a cell the the data goes off. Oddly it replaces the first quotation mark with " ï ".  Here is the source > BWI Business World Inc. - Bags - Plastic 1 Mil 12" x 7" x 23" (BWI) ......... becomes >>> BWI Business World Inc. - Bags - Plastic 1 Mil 12ï¼‚ x 7" x 23" (BWI)> I'm still looking online to no avail.

Comment: What SKU is this?

Comment: The sku is EX-979598. I started to draft another post, should I post this issue as another question? Based on the information I provided I would agree that it changes the scope.

Comment: Use `replaceAll` instead of `replace`. That changes all the characters in the cell. Doesn't fix the `ï¼‚` problem (do you see that there are 3 characters: i, 1/4, and comma) BUT I know for certain that when `Convert_WebInterface` has run, then the content = `BWI Business World Inc. - Bags - Plastic 1 Mil 12＂ x 7＂ x 23＂ (BWI)`. I'm guessing that there is a conversion taking place when the content is saved to the file. Yes, I think you/we have enough information now to warrant a new question. Possibly the answer resolves around the choice of character to replace the double quote??? Best wishes.

Comment: My bad. It's not an "i" at all. it is "lowercase ï, a symbol used in various languages written with the Latin alphabet; it can be read as the letter I with diaeresis, I-umlaut or I-trema." ref [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%8F#:~:text=%C3%8F%2C%20lowercase%20%C3%AF%2C%20is%20a,%2Dumlaut%20or%20I%2Dtrema.)

Comment: OK. Open the csv file with a text editor; you should see that the quotation marks are intact. And/or, open the csv file in Google Sheets; outcome = ditto. I _think_ that the problem is **Excel**. Getting there slowly.

Comment: Tedinoz, here is the new question link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78157574/google-sheet-export-range-container-special-characters-as-csv

Comment: Tedinoz, Tanake tackled the solution on the new post. Very different script though, I'm still going over it.

Comment: Any solution offered by @Tanaike is guaranteed to be good. Glad you have resolution now.

Answer (score 1):

For all the context you shared and all the script needs to do, I want to focus on this piece of it:

> In short, I need to export columns based on their header value and change the header value that shows in the export.

So, if you have this *source* data:

```js
[
  ['alpha', 'beta',  'episilon', 'delta', 'zeta',  'gamma'],
  ['r1_c1', 'r1_c2', 'r1_c5',    'r1_c4', 'r1_c6', 'r1_c3'],
  ['r2_c1', 'r2_c2', 'r2_c5',    'r2_c4', 'r2_c6', 'r2_c3'],
]
```

and you need to end up with this *target* data:

```js
[
  ['Alpha', 'Delta', 'Beta' ],
  ['r1_c1', 'r1_c4', 'r1_c2'],
  ['r2_c1', 'r2_c4', 'r2_c2'],
]
```

Then, maybe the following will help.  It looks like you know how to get data out of and back into a sheet, so I'll focus on a simple data structure to define the mapping between source and target names, and how to use that to query the source data for actual column positions.

What you named `allvalues` I've named `srcData`, and I get it like so:

```js
const srcData = SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();

console.log(srcData);
```

[getDataRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getDataRange()) looks to do the same thing you do to get all values, but without having to specify the bounds yourself.  Importantly, it includes the header row (same as my sample source data, above):

```js
[
  ['alpha', 'beta',  'episilon', 'delta', 'zeta',  'gamma'],
  ['r1_c1', 'r1_c2', 'r1_c5',    'r1_c4', 'r1_c6', 'r1_c3'],
  ['r2_c1', 'r2_c2', 'r2_c5',    'r2_c4', 'r2_c6', 'r2_c3'],
]
```

I'll slice the source data into a header row and "data" rows to make the subsequent steps of finding the important source columns and then transfering those cells more clear:

```js
const srcHeader = srcData[0];
const srcRows = srcData.slice(1);
```

Next, I'll define a mapping between pairs of name values, like:

```js
const tgtNamesFromSrcNames = [
  ['Alpha', 'alpha'],
  ['Delta', 'delta'],
  ['Beta',  'beta' ],
];
```

(If you need to make sure the target columns also fall into a particular order, you can set that by moving a pair up or down.)

The key is to figure out where in the source header the important column names appear.  First, get the source column names by themselves:

```js
const srcNames = tgtNamesFromSrcNames.map(x => x[1]);
```

then, use that array of names to look for them in the header:

```js
const srcIndexes = srcNames.map(x => {
  const i = srcHeader.indexOf(x);
  if (i == -1) throw Error(`could not find exported source column named '${x}' in source header [${srcHeader}]`);
  return [i, x];
});
console.log(srcIndexes);
```

(If a specified name isn't found, it throws a helpful error.)

srcIndexes looks like:

```js
[ [ 0, 'alpha' ], [ 3, 'delta' ], [ 1, 'beta' ] ]
```

and when viewed in relation to the header:

```js
[ 'alpha', 'beta', 'episilon', 'delta', 'zeta', 'gamma' ]
```

I can see that I now know the positions of my colums-of-interest in the header: alpha (0), beta (1), and delta (3). I also can see that the export order is alpha, delta, beta, which will map to Alpha, Delta, Beta.

I can then use these to pull values out of each row in the source data rows.  I'll loop over the source data rows, and for each row pull out the cells that correspond to the specifc column names by looping over srcIndexes:

```js
const tgtRows = srcRows.map(srcRow => srcIndexes.map(([i,]) => srcRow[i]));
```

which is equivalent to:

```js
const tgtRows = [];
for (const srcRow of srcRows) {
  const newRow = [];
  for (const [i,] of srcIndexes) {
    newRow.push(srcRow[i]);
  }
  tgtRows.push(newRow);
}
```

Finally, build the target header from the array of mapped values:

```js
const tgtHeader = tgtNamesFromSrcNames.map(x => x[0]);
```

Looking at all of those data structures together:

```js
const tgtData = [tgtHeader, ...tgtRows];

console.log(srcData);
console.log(tgtNamesFromSrcNames.map((x, i) => `srcName: '${x[1]}' srcIdx: ${srcIndexes[i]} tgtName: '${x[0]}'`));
console.log(tgtData);
```

We can see each source column's name and where it was found (index), and the target name for export:

```js
[
  [ 'alpha', 'beta',  'episilon', 'delta', 'zeta',  'gamma' ],
  [ 'r1_c1', 'r1_c2', 'r1_c5',    'r1_c4', 'r1_c6', 'r1_c3' ],
  [ 'r2_c1', 'r2_c2', 'r2_c5',    'r2_c4', 'r2_c6', 'r2_c3' ],
]
[
  "srcName: 'alpha' srcIdx: 0 tgtName: 'Alpha'",
  "srcName: 'delta' srcIdx: 3 tgtName: 'Delta'",
  "srcName: 'beta'  srcIdx: 1 tgtName: 'Beta'",
]
[
  [ 'Alpha', 'Delta', 'Beta'  ],
  [ 'r1_c1', 'r1_c4', 'r1_c2' ],
  [ 'r2_c1', 'r2_c4', 'r2_c2' ],
]
```

Here's the whole thing.  I also changed the export order:

```js
const srcData = SpreadsheetApp
  .getActiveSheet()
  .getDataRange()
  .getValues();

// Slice the source data up into a header row and data rows
const srcHeader = srcData[0];
const srcRows = srcData.slice(1);

/** Order the items by the final position of the target column: [tgtCol, srcCol][]. */
const tgtNamesFromSrcNames = [
  ['Delta', 'delta'],
  ['Beta', 'beta'],
  ['Alpha', 'alpha'],
];

/** Source-column names in target-column order. */
const srcNames = tgtNamesFromSrcNames.map(x => x[1]);

/** Source-column index/name pairs in target-column order: [srcIdx, srcCol][]. */
const srcIndexes = srcNames.map(x => {
  const i = srcHeader.indexOf(x);
  if (i == -1) throw Error(`could not find exported source column named '${x}' in source header [${srcHeader}]`);
  return [i, x];
});

const tgtHeader = tgtNamesFromSrcNames.map(x => x[0]);
const tgtRows = srcRows.map(srcRow => srcIndexes.map(([i,]) => srcRow[i]));
const tgtData = [tgtHeader, ...tgtRows];

console.log(tgtData);
```

```js
[
  [ 'Delta', 'Beta', 'Alpha'  ],
  [ 'r1_c4', 'r1_c2', 'r1_c1' ],
  [ 'r2_c4', 'r2_c2', 'r2_c1' ]
]
```

Comment: Zach Young, thanks for the help. I really appreciate all of the information you provided as it was a great help. I struggled with getting the dates back in but the answer you provided I will definitely be using for several other CSV exports I am doing.